# Permission denied when running script via ssh

Tags: ssh, permissions, scripting, key-authentication

I wrote a script which downloads via `scp` and installs some packages. SSH keys are added to host and when I run

```
[root@HostB ~]# ./myscript
```

everything is ok and packages are downloaded via scp without asking for password.

I need to run this script via `ssh` but when I try

```
[root@HostA ~]# ssh root@HostB "./myscript"
```

I get Permission denied (publickey,password) error.

When I'm trying to use `ssh -t` I get a password enquiry in place when `scp` command in myscript is executing.

Comment: from HostA, can you `ssh root@HostB` ?

Comment: do you have an SSH agent running on HostA?

Comment: @glenn jackman: sure,  there is also key added. Problem with permissions is during executing scp in script running on host B.

Comment: Do you get the same results if you use the full path to the script?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your problem has nothing to do with `myscript`. What you actually need to figure out is why your `scp` commands complete without a password prompt when you run them locally, but ask for a password when you're running remotely. My guess is you're relying on an SSH agent for keys that is not being forwarded in the remote script execution case.

Answer (score 1):

Answer= Add "bash"

How to SSH into a Computer and Execute a Script from Jenkinsfile:
The file is called "Shell Script.sh" in directory "/home/username/Shell Script Directory"

From Jenkinsfile:

```
sh "sudo ssh -i /home/user/myPemFile.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -n username@192.168.11.12 \"bash /home/username/Shell\\ Script\\ Directory/Shell\\ Script.sh\" "
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be because you don't have `PasswordAuthentication` set to yes.

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Add this to the `sshd_config` on the machines and try again. This should prompt for password.

Another solution would be to take the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on HostA and add it to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the HostB

Now that you have password authentication enabled, you can install the authorized keys with this command:

```
ssh-copy-id HostB
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you're using `scp` inside your script to download packages. Your problem is with that bit. The issue is that, when you run ssh in this form:

```
ssh user@host command
```

... there is no pseudo terminal allocated to the script that is running. `scp` tries to prompt for a password, but it needs a pseudo terminal for that, so without one, you get the permission denied error (which is coming from a failed password authentication attempt). If you use `ssh -t`, then there is a pseudo terminal, and the password prompt works. What you need to figure out is why `scp` is prompting for a password when run remotely, but not when run from an interactive ssh session. That's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

> Permission denied (publickey,password) error

Its got nothing to do with the permissions on the script. You are failing to establish an ssh connection. Try just getting a shell on the remote system first.

```
ssh -vv root@HostB
```

BTW it's generally not a good idea to allow direct access to the root account via ssh - and the error you have shown is what one would expect if the sshd is configured with PermitRootLogin=No. The right way to solve this is to provision an acocunt with appropriate sudo privileges and use that to run the command.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like it still wants you to input the password.  When you SSH to HostB from HostA, does it ask for a password?

If it does, you will need to change your `ssh_config` file (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on RHEL/Centos) to have:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

If `PasswordAuthentication` is set to yes, it will always prompt you for a password.

Comment: No, this is backwards (and may lock you out of the host if you don't have public key auth set up). By disabling password authentication, you aren't adding any ways into a host, you're only locking ways out. If a password prompt appears, that is because other methods have already failed.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
ssh root@hostb 'bash -s' < local-script.sh
```

Comment: OP's problem is about password being asked, not sending the script.

Comment: not related to the question.